# Ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.7 - ImportError: No module named enum

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, enums, ubuntu-16.04

First time using Ubuntu. I installed Anaconda 4.1.1 (Python 2.7). I was trying to use enum but I got an import error.

```
import enum
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-13948d6bb7b8>", line 1, in <module>
import enum

ImportError: No module named enum
```

I tried using:
    conda install -c menpo enum=0.4.4
but it didn't work.

I also tried installing enum from this link - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34#downloads

None of these solutions have worked for me so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What was your installation error from pypi downloads?

Comment: `enum34` is the one you want.  Try `conda install ... enum34...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `pip install enum34`. Enum is in the Python 3 stdlib. `enum34` is a backport.