# Installing Azure support for Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, python-packaging

I am trying to get Ansible to deploy resources to the Azure cloud and I am having an error while getting it in to work.  I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04

I have installed ansible by running the following:

```
 - sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
 - sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
 - sudo apt-get update
 - sudo apt-get install ansible
```

I also installed pip by running the command

```
 - sudo easy_install pip
```

And that all was done to get ansible install on the server. Then I started with the Azure components for Ansible by following the instructions given [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_azure.html).

I ran the command `sudo pip install "azure==2.0.0rc5"` to get the Azure Python SDK.  Then I created a simple yaml file to create a resource group and when I ran the playbook by running the command `ansible-playbook test.yml -vvv` the following error was returned:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true,
>   "invocation": {"module_args": {"ad_user": null, "append_tags": true,
>   "client_id": null, "force": false, "location": null, "name": "test",
>   "password": null, "profile": null, "secret": null, "state": "present",
>   "subscription_id": null, "tags": null, "tenant": null}, "module_name":
>   "azure_rm_resourcegroup"},  "msg": "Do you have azure==2.0.0rc5
>   installed? Try `pip install azure==2.0.0rc5`- No module named enum"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible suggestion in this error message is really confusing. Usually you need to add a few more packages besides `azure==2.0.0rc5`.

Pay attention to the package name given in the following part of the message:

> No module named **enum**

So in this case try:

```
sudo pip install enum
```

<sup>One thing to check is: [Ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.7 - ImportError: No module named enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670197/ubuntu-16-04-python-2-7-importerror-no-module-named-enum) I'm not sure if it applies in this situation, it looks like 16.04 problem. I did have `enum` installed by default.</sup>

From my experience you'll also need:

```
sudo pip install msrest
sudo pip install msrestazure
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue for me but I think there needs to be more configuration\setup done to get the two communicate.  When I run the playbook I get an invalid username password back from Azure

Comment: This is out of date for Ansible 3.0+ / ansible-core 2.10+

Answer (score 5):

**New answer for Ansible 3.0+ / ansible-core 2.10+:**

To install Azure support, use the [Ansible Azure collection](https://galaxy.ansible.com/azure/azcollection) as follows:

```
# Install dependencies
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible-collections/azure/dev/requirements-azure.txt
pip install -r requirements-azure.txt

# Install collection
ansible-galaxy collection install azure.azcollection
```

- [requirements-azure.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible-collections/azure/dev/requirements-azure.txt) specifies versions for all libraries, so it's best to reinstall these if you upgrade the collection version
- consider checking this in to 'pin' versions of dependencies
- you may want to pin the collection version as well

As an [Ansible collection](https://www.ansible.com/blog/getting-started-with-ansible-collections), this Ansible Azure support can now be more rapidly updated outside the Ansible core release process.

*Updated for [ansible-core](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-core/devel/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#releases-and-maintenance) 2.10+, which is included in Ansible 3.0 and higher.*

---

**Original answer** worked up to Ansible 2.9:

The simplest and most reliable way to install the Azure packages for Ansible is:

```
pip install ansible[azure]==2.8.6
```

This installs the Azure dependencies required for this Ansible version.  If you want to use the latest version, omit the `==2.8.6` part.

This works because the Ansible project defines the [exact dependency versions](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.9.9/packaging/requirements/requirements-azure.txt) (as of 2.9.9) that it needs for Azure support as an 'extra' in its Python packaging setup.

- if you're interested, there is more about this in the [Python packaging docs](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-setuptools-extras).