# Using google-cloud-tasks with python 2.7 on app-engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-tasks

I'm working on migrating a Python 2.7/1st Gen/GAE app to Python 3/2nd Gen/GAE.

My current step is replacing `google.appengine.ext.deferred` with the [Python Client for Cloud Tasks API](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudtasks/latest/index.html).

Here is where I'm at:

- Still using Python 2.7
- Latest updates with `gcloud components update`
- Following the Python Client docs, I added `google-cloud-tasks==1.5.0` to my `requirements.txt`
- `google-cloud-tasks` needs `grpcio` so I added `- name: grpcio\n version: latest` to `app.yaml`
- Now `dev_appserver.py` is giving me the error `ImportError: No module named enum`

I'm not finding much documentation online so I'm wondering...   Is it possible to use `google-cloud-tasks` with Python 2.7 on app engine?

If so, how do I fix the last error above?

Comment: In that document said that you can still use the version `google-cloud-tasks==1.5.0`. It seems the error more on the `enum`. The error similar to this questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828206/importerror-no-module-named-enum), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670197/ubuntu-16-04-python-2-7-importerror-no-module-named-enum), and  [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731222/importerror-no-module-named-enum-on-python-2-7). I hope it helps

Comment: The solution might be to reinstall everything with `pip` and `--no-cache-dir`.